# flask session overwrites another session

Tags: python, session, flask

I have stored the userid into a `flask` session. But when another user opens the browser and sets the session userid. My current session userid changes. Is it possible. I am also using a `global class variable` which gets initiated from the session as below. Because of this all process gets messed up when more than one user uses the url. I am running python flask using `nohup`

```
login
@app.route('/mainlogin',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():
    try:
        if request.method =='POST':
            session['uid'] = request.form['db_user']

main
@app.route('/main',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def mainindex():
    global clsmain
    uid=session.get('uid')
    clsmain=clsmain(uid)

@app.route('/viewlog',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def viewlog():
     return render_template('log.html',status="<br>" + clsmain.readlog())
```

Why does session overwrites. Or is it global variable acting as the same value across sessions?

Comment: Without knowing what `clsmain` is I can't say, but something about it smells fishy to me.

Comment: Why are you using a global variable?

Comment: @sberry clsmain is a class with common variables and functions.

Comment: @BrenBarn global variable is used to access clsmain object in another page

Comment: added viewlog sample to show the use of global variable.

Comment: Don't use a global variable for that.  Use a session variable or some such thing.

Comment: Like session['obj']=clsmain  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with flask session but the `global` variable. Global variable holds same value across sessions(or flask does not handle global variables based on sessions) . Found reference from this link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273989/flask-global-variables-and-sessions](http://link)

Comment: your link is dead.